# Confluent failed to find any class that implements connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I go to https://www.confluent.io/installation/, and download the Confluent platform in ZIP file under "Local", after unzip it, I continue to start the confluent platform by the following command:

```
confluent local services start
```

I can see all the service started correctly, and I able to view my control center throw browser.

And this is the folder structure of my Confluent platform:

[image]

After that, I referring to [this](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-sftp/current/source-connector/index.html#configuration-properties), to install the sftp connector.

I install the connector by the following command:

```
confluent-hub install confluentinc/kafka-connect-sftp:latest
```

Command run successfully, and I can see the folder created in /share/confluent-hub-components

[image]

Based on the guide from confluent [website](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-sftp/current/source-connector/index.html#configuration-properties), I need to create 1 file call `sftp.json`, and then load the connector by following command:

```
confluent local services connect connector load CsvSFTP --config sftp.json
```

However, I am hitting error like follow:

```
[meow@localhost confluent-7.0.1]$ confluent local services connect connector load CsvSFTP --config sftp.json
The local commands are intended for a single-node development environment only,
NOT for production usage. https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

{
  "error_code": 500,
  "message": "Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.sftp.SftpCsvSourceConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class io.confluent.connect.replicator.ReplicatorSourceConnector, name='io.confluent.connect.replicator.ReplicatorSourceConnector', version='7.0.1', encodedVersion=7.0.1, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/home/meow/Workspace/confluentPlatform/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/kafka-connect-replicator/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector', version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/home/meow/Workspace/confluentPlatform/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/kafka/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector', version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/home/meow/Workspace/confluentPlatform/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/kafka/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector', version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/home/meow/Workspace/confluentPlatform/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/kafka/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector', version='7.0.1-ce', encodedVersion=7.0.1-ce, type=connector, typeName='connector', location='file:/home/meow/Workspace/confluentPlatform/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/acl/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector', version='7.0.1-ce', encodedVersion=7.0.1-ce, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='file:/home/meow/Workspace/confluentPlatform/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/acl/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector', version='7.0.1-ce', encodedVersion=7.0.1-ce, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/home/meow/Workspace/confluentPlatform/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/acl/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector', version='7.0.1-ce', encodedVersion=7.0.1-ce, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/home/meow/Workspace/confluentPlatform/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/acl/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector', version='7.0.1-ce', encodedVersion=7.0.1-ce, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/home/meow/Workspace/confluentPlatform/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/acl/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector', version='7.0.1-ce', encodedVersion=7.0.1-ce, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/home/meow/Workspace/confluentPlatform/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/acl/'}"
```

Looks like my confluent platform did not load the connector that I install, then I go to edit the plugin.path value in `connect-standalone.properties`, add in the newly install connector path:

```
plugin.path=/usr/share/java,/home/meow/Workspace/confluentPlatform/confluent-7.0.1/share/confluent-hub-components
```

And then follow by restart my confluent platform, and try again, result still same, error message still same. Which mistake I have made?

And how can I know the `connect-standalone.properties` is being loaded when starting Confluent Platform, because I check my log in `/home/meow/Workspace/confluentPlatform/confluent-7.0.1/logs`, its not append there unless `schema-registry.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`confluent` CLI should be using `etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties` for the schema registry config, not any of the standalone ones.

Try updating the `plugin.path` in the other file and trying again.

---

> how can I know the connect-standalone.properties is being loaded

Try `ps -aux | grep Connect`

---

If you are using a Linux host, it's recommended you use APT/YUM installation methods, not the tarball

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/installing_cp/overview.html

Comment: You are right, need to specific the connector path to `etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties`. I am still not understand, how come its related to schema registry? I thought it suppose to be the standalone ones?

Comment: That's not really relevant to the problem. The Confluent CLI starts the Schema Registry as well. Most of the other services then reference it. There's also a `connect-avro-standalone.properties` but it is not used... More specifically, the distributed service is started because only then are you able to use `load` command